# How to remove subdirectories from moodle url?

Tags: php, moodle

I 'm a rookie in PHP and I need to remove the subdirectories from the moodle url during navigation.
This question may have been asked a lot before and all the solution suggested to modify the .htacess, but all the solutions provided didn't go along with [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) which apparently indicates that something has to be done in the code.

For example, this [solution](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109881/how-to-remove-subdirectory-folders-from-the-url-using-htaccess) here looks promising but I didn't quite understand anything due to my inexperience in PHP. So if someone has done it with Moodle specifically to hide plugins subdirectories, like for example: http://example.com/mod/pluginname/view.php?id=6 and made look like this: http://example.com/view.php?id=6, the help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're going to find this very difficult to do with rewrite rules, because the information about which plugin you are trying to access (the /mod/pluginname part) is pretty much essential in order for Moodle to determine what to display. Maybe a better question to start with is why would you want to do this?

Comment: @davosmith my client uses a plugin for an open source web conferencing app that is eligible for branding and he wants to hide the pluginname from the URL. I tried to change the name better than hiding it, but I ended up crashing moodle because the inside code is tightly coupled to the directory